# Why does Rambam mention cities of refuge in separate halacha than Bilaam etc.?

Tags: rambam, messiah, mishneh-torah, city-of-refuge

B"H

The Rambam in the beginning of the laws of kings chapter 11 brings the proofs from the Torah for how we know Moshiach.

The first proof is a verse from the Torah saying Hashem will "return us" to the land.

The second, in that same halacha (#1) is the passage of the prophet Bilaam, and the Rambam explains which verses in that passage refer to Moshiach.

Then the Rambam finishes the first halacha, starts the second, and brings a third proof from the cities of refuge.

The question is, if the first halacha is, seemingly, to bring the different proofs from the Torah regarding Moshiach, then why does he mention the cities of refuge in it's own halacha, and not together with the other two?

Or if he wants to list each proof in a separate halacha, then why not list the proof from the passage of Bilaam in the second halacha, and the cities of refuge in the third?

[Source](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188356/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-11.htm)

Comment: It's not Rambam that mentions the first two proofs in the first halacha, and the third proof in third halacha. It's the editors of the common editions of the Mishneh Torah who do that.  In [Mechon Mamre's edition](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e511.htm#2) (based on Yemenite manuscripts), the proofs are split over several halachot. In some [old printed editions](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42253&st=&pgnum=740), all three proofs are grouped together.

Comment: Related: "[What is the intention of the Moshiach proofs from the Torah, brought by Rambam?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/121756/1368)" (This question is basically point/difficulty No. 2 in that question.)

Comment: @TamirEvan hi. Even in machon mamre they list the original halacha number, look at halacha 5 there. That other link has everything grouped as one halacha, so maybe the editors there edited them all out. The linked question doesn't have that point answered

Comment: @YakkOv Mechon Mamre looks like it is using Rav Kapach's edition of Rambam. He left the common (what you call original) numbers in his edition because they are universal, even though in his opinion they were mistaken.

Comment: @n.t ok. Either way the question is valid for those who follow the views that the numbers were not mistaken

Comment: Who follows the view that the numbers were not mistaken? I don't think anyone specifically holds that way

Comment: As others are mentioning here, the grouping of halachos is not that clear. But see the Rambam's own words in his Introduction: His grouping into chapters was important and based on topic, his grouping into halachos was more a matter of convenience of memorization and less fundamental. https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Transmission_of_the_Oral_Law.43?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @MichoelR the "halachos" the Rambam is referring to in his introduction are the general categories of chapters, also known as "halachos". But either way, one still has to explain it

Comment: @YakkOv The quote I gave describes two different things called "halachos". Don't read what I said, read what the Rambam said. He breaks the "halachos" into perakim, and the perakim into "smaller halachos". We are talking about the second type.

Comment: @MichoelR I understand, that is the question. The first set of halachos are by category, the smaller set is to keep in one's memory. Since the Rambam himself ordered even the smaller set of halachos, one can ask a question regarding how they are ordered. It would be much easier to stick into one's memory this idea if each of the proofs were in a separate halacha, or all together as one

Comment: @YakkOv One can definitely ask a question - but the answer may well be something about what the Rambam thought would be easier to memorize, the length of the various proofs or who knows what. It surely makes the question weaker.

Comment: @michoelr the question is to understand why the Rambam thought one way over the other. Seemingly the way such a smart person would think should have at least some logic to it, hence the question. That's all I have to say about it, the rest should be self understood